# Are there any rewards for Splatoon 2's rhythm game?

Tags: splatoon-2

Splatoon 2 includes a hidden Rhythm Minigame/Sound Test mode accessible in Inkopolis Plaza. It includes 42 playable songs, each completable on Normal and Hard difficulty.

**Aside from the gold and silver squid badges displayed after beating an individual track, are there any rewards for completing every song?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Polygon](https://www.polygon.com/2017/7/11/15952642/splatoon-2-preview-rhythm-game-squid-beatz-2.) is reporting that there are no rewards:

> Going through each of these tracks is a pleasure not because of any rigorous gameplay or rad rewards — **there are none of the latter**